# Dotnet unit test with Coverlet - How to get a custom coverage file name instead of "coverage.cobertura.xml"?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core

The bare `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"` command generates code coverage file as `coverage.cobertura.xml` for each test project.

I have a solution with several unit tests and integration tests. To simplify report generation for each type of tests, I would like to put the test type also in the generated file name such as unit_tests.coverage.cobertura.xml.